# CSS: Skirting style

Tags: html, css, styles

Is it possible by using styles to create an `DIV` like this?

[image]
[image]

I mean the structure of the plinth. A similar 3D effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of possible. You can use `background: linear-gradient()` for the colors and multiple div's with `border-radius` for the shape and different heights and widths, e.g.:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}
.layer1 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.layer2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 280px;
  float: right;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  background: #b5b5b5;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b5b5b5 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b5b5b5 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b5b5b5 0%, #eeeeee 48%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b5b5b5', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.layer3 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 230px;
  float: right;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="layer1"></div>
  <div class="layer2"></div>
  <div class="layer3"></div>
</div>
```

Just play around with the properties a little bit and I'm sure you will get nice results. The above is just a quick ugly example...

**Limitations**: With this approach it's only possible to build convex curves.

Comment: Its looks perfect - Thank you